# Preserve HttpContext when going async with WebAPI (Medium Trust)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am building a set of ASP.Net hosted WebAPI services that must use an old library which depends heavily on HttpContext.Current.  I am having trouble ensuring that context is preserved in all the methods that participate in an async call.  I have tried several variations with await/Task.Wait and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() on the below code.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<IEnumerable<string>> ContinueWith()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");  //or another culture that is not the default on your machine
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        var output = new List<string> { TestOutput("Action start") };

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return TestOutput("In Task");
            }).ContinueWith(slowString =>
            {
                output.Add(slowString.Result);

                output.Add(TestOutput("Action end"));
                return output as IEnumerable<string>;
            });

        output.Add(TestOutput("Action Mid"));

        return task;
    }

    private string TestOutput(string label)
    {
        var s = label + " ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        s += " " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.EnglishName;
        s += HttpContext.Current == null ? " No Context" : " Has Context";
        Debug.WriteLine(s);
        return s;
    }
```

I would like to be able to ensure that the CurrentCulture is fr-FR, and that HttpContext.Current is not null at each point where TestOutput is called.  I have not succeeded in doing that for the "In Task" call with anything I have tried. Also in some of my test thread id never varies suggesting that I have effectively removed the asynchronicity of the method.  How can I ensure that the culture and HttpContext.Current are preserved at each call to TestOutput, and that the code is free to run on different threads?

Capturing HttpContext.Current in a closure and then simply setting it again will not work for me as I need to support Medium Trust which will throw a security exception when calling the HttpContext.Current setter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Context is preserved whenever you `await` tasks.

What you're seeing is that there's no context for thread pool tasks (`Task.Run`, `TaskFactory.StartNew`, or for that matter `BackgroundWorker` or `Thread` or `Delegate.BeginInvoke`). This is normal and expected.

So, don't use a thread pool task. Your example code seems to want to do parallel processing with multiple threads having the `HttpContext`, which simply isn't possible.

You can do concurrent `async` methods if you want, but this requires that your `Thread.Sleep` can actually be an `async` method instead of a CPU-based method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Test()
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

  var output = new List<string> { TestOutput("Action start") };

  var task = SlowStringAsync();
  output.Add(TestOutput("Action Mid"));
  output.Add(await task);
  output.Add(TestOutput("Action end"));
  return output;
}

public async Task<string> SlowStringAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  return TestOutput("In Task");
}
```

If your old library is out of your control and you can't make it `async`, then you'll have to call it synchronously. It's acceptable to call a synchronous method from an `async` method in situations like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Test()
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

  var output = new List<string> { TestOutput("Action start") };

  output.Add(TestOutput("Action Mid"));
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  output.Add(TestOutput("Not Really In Task"));
  output.Add(TestOutput("Action end"));
  return output;
}
```

Comment: It was my understanding that AspNetSynchronizationContext is specifically to preserve things like HttpContext when executed on another thread.  Am I misunderstanding, or is AspNetSynchronizationContext just not applicable in this situation?

Comment: `AspNetSynchronizationContext` preserves `HttpContext`, but only one thread can be in a request context at a time. You can't put the context on other threads, but `AspNetSynchronizationContext` is in charge of putting the context on the thread pool thread that resumes the `async` method after it `await`s.

Comment: @StephenCleary - Forgive my ignorance but would `CurrentCulture` be preserved across threads if using the `Task.Factory.StartNew()` method - e.g. `return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {  doSomething(); };`

Comment: @CarlosP: I believe MS just added that with .NET 4.6. Before that, no, culture had to be flowed explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

A little noticed fact, [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) is writable.

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    HttpContext.Current = context;
    // You may want to set CultureInformation here too.

    return TestOutput("In Task");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Simon.  It is a little known fact, however it will cause a security exception when running in Medium Trust which I need to support as noted in the question.

Comment: It's also extremely dangerous since you have multiple threads with the same `HttpContext.Current`, which is specifically *not* designed for multithreaded access.

Comment: I understand it's not the best approach, but with regard to being dangerous due to threading issues, would putting a lock around it help?  Would the closure variable be assigned during the lock, or would it wait until the time it's read?