# async await with .net 4.0 - maintain static context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, c#-5.0

I have an MVC 4.0 site which is using the BCL async/await package.
To preserve HttpContext across the initial thread and the subsequent thread (after the await) I began by creating a closure with a reference to the context like so:

```
   public async Task<ViewResult> GetCustomer(int id)
      {            
       var ctx =  HttpContext.Current;
       ctx["test"] = "test";

       await DoSomeLongRunningIO();

       var test = ctx["test"];
       //do other things with context

       return View();
    }
```

However, I need to call various services after the await. These legacy services call the HttpContext.Current directly. 
So I approached this with the following code, which seemed like a simple way to ensure these services still work as expected.

```
  public async Task<ViewResult> GetCustomer(int id)
      {            
       var ctx =  HttpContext.Current;

       await DoSomeLongRunningIO();

       HttpContext.Current = ctx;

       //call other services which use static references to httpcontext
       return View();
    }
```

This does work, however I have been reading [this answer that suggests it is a bad idea:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557798/preserve-httpcontext-when-going-async-with-webapi-medium-trust)

1. Is this a bad idea, and if so why is it worse than the first example?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that [`async`/`await` in an ASP.NET app on .NET 4.0 is undefined](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx)?

If you upgrade to .NET 4.5, you'll find that `HttpContext` is preserved automatically for you. There's no need for closures or to set it.

Setting `HttpContext.Current` is a bad idea, because you're bypassing the ASP.NET safety checks that ensure there is only one thread at a time with that context.

Comment: thanks for your reply. when we say undefined, what does that mean? (i did read the link but was unclear). I cant use 4.5 at the moment unfortunately. From my code above, I didnt think I would ever be in a position where I have 2 threads with one context at one time? It would always be 1 thread and 1 context (at any one time).

Comment: @jonho: "Undefined" is shorthand for "undefined behavior". That means it won't work right.

Comment: I have decided to use the TPL instead.

Comment: In the post  you cited, it states that the behavior is undefined _if you don't set the *aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext* flag_. What if you set just this flag to true, while still using .Net4 with the BCL package? Would that work as expected (i.e. like having the full .Net4.5 framework)?

Comment: @julealgon: No. The `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` flag was introduced in ASP.NET 4.5. It has no meaning on ASP.NET 4.0.