# How would I pass a Web API Request through Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am having a Web API application in which the controller has Services/Repositories etc. injected into it through Dependency Injection (Unity). Let's assume that I have an `IStuffService` that needs the `IPrincipal` of the current request (or a wrapper around it).

The problem with Web API seems to be that the *only* reliable source of the current Request/User is the `Request` property on the *instance* of the `ApiController`. Anything static (be it `HttpContext.Current`, `CallContext.Get/SetData` or `Thread.Get/SetData`) is not guaranteed to be on the same thread due to the sync nature of Web API.

How do I reliably ensure that Request-specific context is passed through dependencies, and more importantly, that the operation retains the correct `IPrincipal` all the way through the operation?

Two options:

1. Every method that needs an `IPrincipal` has it as an argument to the method - that is the most reliable way, but it also requires me to have that thing in every method signature
2. Inject the IPrincipal into the ctor of the Service, spinning up a new insance of the object graph on every request, using a DependencyOverride in Unity: `container.Resolve(opType, new DependencyOverride(typeof(IPrincipal), principal))`

Option 2 means that my method signatures are clean, but it also means I need to make sure all dependencies are using the TransientLifetimeManager, not a Singleton or even Per-Thread one.

Is there a better solution than I'm not seeing?

Comment: Ideally, do you want your `IStuffService` implementation to be a singleton across all requests?

Comment: @Xenolightning But how would the service get the current `IPrincipal` when I'm making a method call?

Comment: Interesting question, but why would you need an `IPrincipal` for every method in your controller?

Comment: @DavidG I need it in my Service (it's available in my Controller). One example is to log which user made a change, or to determine if a service call is legal given the current user. That's a business-logic-level decision that lives in the service and needs to know who's calling to make that decision.

Comment: @MichaelStum Wouldn't that logic sit better in an `AuthorizeAttribute` for example?

Comment: @DavidG The business logic is doing a lot of different checks based on the action. E.g., Manager X might be able to to Action Y to Employee Z, but only some other State X2 is good. On the other hand, Manager X might always be able to to Action Y2 to Employee Z regardless of state. I would have a whole bunch of Authorize Attributes that describe the semantics of the action. So that could live in the Controller. Web API is only one possible consumer of the logic though, there might also be a Console App or a separate MVC site that doesn't talk through the API.

Comment: And also, despite all the improvements in Unit Testing, Controllers are still much harder to test than Services since I only need to worry about an IPrincipal, not about a RequestContext. From a maintenance standpoint (and experience with issues previously), it makes most sense to move almost all of the business logic/validation into a separate Service-Layer and have the Web API/MVC/Console App be a very small host that just sends stuff down to the service and responses back to the user.

Comment: @MichaelStum If the `IPrincipal` is part of the logic, I'd probably make it a parameter of the action method. That's the only safe way you'd be able to do unit testing.

Comment: @DavidG Indeed, adding it to the method is safe. It's also very verbose as there are dozens of individual service calls :/

Comment: @MichaelStum, I believe `HttpContext.User` should be flowed correctly across `async/await` (within the same HTTP request). Is it not for you?

Comment: @Noseratio See the other answers - in .net 4.0, it's bound to the current thread and was not properly maintained. It seems that in 4.5, this might be fixed. That said, HttpContext.Current is still not that appropriate in Web API because on self-hosted ones there is no HttpContext.Current.

Comment: @MichaelStum, my reply couldn't fit into a comment, so I posted it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24319210/1768303).

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate answer is that our IoC containers need to be changed to support async/await better.

#### Background:

The behavior of async/await around this changed between .NET 4 and .NET 4.5.  In .NET 4.5 the `SynchronizationContext` was introduced and it will correctly restore `HttpContext.Current` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).  However, it is often a best practice to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` (see "Configure Context" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and that specifically requests that the context not be preserved.  In that case you would still have the issue you describe.

#### Answer:

The best answer I have been able to come up with in my own code is to be sure to request the dependency that comes from `HttpContext.Current` (in your case `IPrincipal`) early in the web request so that is is loaded into the container.

I don't have any experience with Unity, but in Ninject this would look something like:

```
kernal.Bind<IPrincipal>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.User).InRequestScope();
```

Then I would be sure to load the `IPrincipal` early in the web request before you have lost the context. Either in BeginRequest or as a dependency of the controller.  That will cause the `IPrincipal` to be loaded into the container for this request.

*Note:* There are still situations where this may not work.  I don't know if Unity has this issue, but I know Ninject does.  It actually uses the HttpContext.Current, to determine what request is active.  So if you try to resolve something from the container later, like a service locator or factory then it may not be able to resolve.

Comment: are you sure this solves the problem when we execute code another thread (asynch, await, or any other methods,...) ?

Comment: how can the container know that the new thread is `related` with the current thread which has the context?

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> @MichaelStum, I believe HttpContext.User should be flowed correctly
>   across async/await (within the same HTTP request). Is it not for you?
>   –  Noseratio 17 hours ago
>
> @Noseratio See the other answers - in .net 4.0, it's bound to the
>   current thread and was not properly maintained. It seems that in 4.5,
>   this might be fixed. That said, HttpContext.Current is still not that
>   appropriate in Web API because on self-hosted ones there is no
>   HttpContext.Current.

AFAIK, there's no proper support for `async/await` in ASP.NET 4.0 anyway (you probably can use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` for the language support, but there is no ASP.NET runtime support, so you'd have to [resort to `AsyncManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21981799/1768303) to implement the TAP pattern).

That said, I'm 99% sure `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` would still be correctly flowed across `await` continuations in ASP.NET 4.0. That's because it gets flowed as a part of `ExecutionContext` flow, rather than by synchronization context. As to `HtttContext.Current.User`, I'm not sure if it would flow correctly in ASP.NET 4.0 (although it certainly does in ASP.NET 4.5).

I've re-read your question, but could find an explicit complaint about `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` not being correctly flowed. Are you experiencing this issue in existing code (if so, it probably would be a bug in ASP.NET)?

Here's a list of related questions, answered with some great insights by Stephen Cleary:

- [Understanding context in C# 5 async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12456115/1768303)
- [Why is an "await Task.Yield()" required for Thread.CurrentPrincipal to flow correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16653308/1768303)
- [Using ASP.NET Web API, my ExecutionContext isn't flowing in async actions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15964244/1768303)

This blog post by Scott Hanselman is also related, although he speaks about WebForms:

- [System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal vs. System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User or why FormsAuthentication can be subtle](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx)

If you're concerned about **self-hosting scenarios**, I believe `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` will still be flowed correctly there (once having been set to a correct identity). If you want to flow any other properties (besides [those which get automatically flowed with `ExecutionContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17242094/1768303)), you can roll out your own synchronization context. Another option (not so nice, IMO) is to [use custom awaiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753055/1768303).

Finally, if you face a situation where you actually require thread affinity across `await` continuation (much like in a client side UI app), you have such option, too (again, using a custom synchronization context):

- [How to use non-thread-safe async/await APIs and patterns with ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20993007/1768303)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question I have worked with option one (in the question) and, it works.

UPDATE: I deleted my answer as I realized I've posted something that doesn't work.
Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Request is not available yet when the constructor is called. This will not work

Answer (score -1):

> How do I reliably ensure that Request-specific context is passed
>   through dependencies, and more importantly, that the operation retains
>   the correct IPrincipal all the way through the operation?

I don't think you should do this. Your service is a **lower layer** than your Api controller. Your service should not depend on any classes related to the **higher layer**, otherwise your service **could not be reused**, for example: when you need to build a win forms application on top of the existing services.

`IPrincipal` is not appropriate to be injected into our services as **it's web application related** . When we pass this information down to lower layers (service), we should pass our **neutral-classes** or just a **userId** to **decouple** our services from the application using it.

You should **define your own classes for Users and anything request-related** to be used in our services layer as it's more **domain-related**. With this, your service-layer is application-layer (web, win forms, console,..) agnostic:

```
public class AppPrincipal : IAppPrincipal
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string Role { get; set; }
   //other properties
   public AppPrincipal() {

   }
   public AppPrincipal(int userId, string role):this() {
       UserId  = userId;
       Role = role;
   }
}
```

Then you can register `IAppPrincipal` as per-request scope in your web application and populate all the properties using your `IPrincipal`. The will initialize your `IAppPrincipal` for your entire object graph before any `await/async` calls. Example code with Unity:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IAppPrincipal>(
                new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
                new InjectionFactory(c => CreateAppPrincipal()));
}
public IAppPrincipal CreateAppPrincipal()
{
    var principal = new AppPrincipal();
    principal.UserId = //Retrieve userId from your IPrincipal (HttpContext.Current.User)
    principal.Role = //Retrieve role from your IPrincipal (HttpContext.Current.User)
    return principal;
}
```

The key here is that we already decouple our service layer from the web. If you need to reuse your service layer to build a windows form or console application, you could register `IAppPrincipal` as singleton and populate it differently.

We don't need to deal with platform-related problems like `async/await`

Comment: Does not answer the question at all.  As he stated, `HttpContext.Current` may not be correct when accessed after an `await`.

Comment: @Jeff Walker Code Ranger: it looks like that this is not a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557798/preserve-httpcontext-when-going-async-with-webapi-medium-trust

Comment: HttpContext.Current also doesn't exist if the API is Self-Hosted as far as I know.

Comment: @Michael Stum: That's what I mean in my first point. Your service layer is `tightly coupled` with your application layer. It cannot work with console, win forms,... because there is no HttpContext.

Comment: @KhanhTO But that's why I want to use an IPrincipal. The Service takes the IPrincipal, but it's the job of the host to make sure it has a service with that IPrincipal. This is the problem I'm facing: I have an IPrincipal in the Web API Controller and need it in the service through whatever many indirections and async/await blocks (with possible thread switches) are in between.

Comment: @Michael Stum: I also don't think `IPrincipal` is appropriate to be injected into services as it should just be a normal user in your application (not an external dependency).

Comment: @Michael Stum: about the threading, this is a general problem. All we're trying to do are just `workarounds` as we should not implement our application this way. There is no solution that covers 100% of the cases, let's say your service code spawn a thread to execute a background task.

Comment: @MichaelStum: I have updated the answer, the idea is the same but use a different approach, please have a look and give your opinion on this, thanks.