# Consume HttpContext Cache with threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, caching, httpcontext

I have the following cache implementation for my application:

```
public static class Keys
{
    public const string CacheKey = "cachekey";
}

public interface ICache
{
    string QueryCachedData(string param);
}
```

the data is loaded when the application starts in Global.asax

```
//Global.asax
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //instantiates the repository
    HttpContext.Current.Application[Keys.CacheKey] = repository.getDataView();
}
```

the implementation recover the data from HttpContext.Current

```
public class Cache : ICache
{
    private Cache() { }
    private static Cache _instance = null;
    public static Cache GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new Cache();
        return _instance;
    }
    private System.Data.DataView GetCachedData()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Application[Keys.CacheKey] == null)
        {
            //instantiates the repository
            HttpContext.Current.Application[Keys.CacheKey] = repository.getDataView();
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Application[Keys.CacheKey] as System.Data.DataView;
    }
    private readonly Object _lock = new Object();
    public string QueryCachedData(string param)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var data = GetCachedData();
            //Execute query
            return result; 
        }
    }
}
```

at some point i need consume some third party web service with the following class using the cache...

```
public class ThirdPartyWebserviceConsumer
{
    ICache _cache;
    int _provider;
    public ThirdPartyWebserviceConsumer(int provider, ICache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _provider = provider;
    }
    public result DoSomething()
    {
        var info = _cache.QueryCachedData(param);
    }
}
```

...using multi-thread:

```
public List<Result> Foo(ICache cache, List<int> collectionOfProviders)
{
    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var provider in collectionOfProviders)
    {
        var task = new Task<Result>(() => new ThirdPartyWebserviceConsumer(provider, cache).DoSomething());
        task.Start();
        task.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            results.Add(task.Result);
        });
        taskList.Add(task);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    return results;
}
```

My problem is that HttpContext.Current.Application is null in the thead context.
What options do I have? there are some form to access the HttpContext in thread? or maybe another type of cache that could be shared between the threads?

Comment: You don't seem to access HttpContext.Current in the multithreaded code block. Can you please give more details, like a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: it throws reference not set to an instance of an object in GetCachedData because HttpContext.Current is null. I have edited the question and added the task.start ()

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557798/preserve-httpcontext-when-going-async-with-webapi-medium-trust

Comment: There is another problem, the "Foo" method is placed into a class library that does not reference to System.Web, and i dont want to add it. so i cannot do:
var context = HttpContext.Current;
...
HttpContext.Current = context;

Comment: The why don't you just (as Eric J. suggested in his answer) pass the cached data to the background thread? Better yet, since you only have one item in your cache, you can also make it a static variable or put it in a static Dictionary in the Cache class and can remove the HttpContext dependency. This will make your Cache class re-usable in desktop applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that HttpContext.Current.Application is null in the thead context. What options do I have?

HttpContext.Current is bound to the managed thread processing the current request.

If you need data from the current context for another thread, you need to copy that data out of the current context first and pass it to your separate thread.